# #arrow::after with Korean characters

Tags: html, css, select, cjk

Greetings and salutations. I am presently developing the CSS for a Language Select, while my partner works on the script part. I've run into small issue that I was hoping I could get some help with.

There are 8 Languages we are working with: Deutsch, English, Español, Français, Italiano, 한국어, Português, and 中文. The languages that use latin characters seem to work all fine and dandy, however, The oriental languages want to run top to bottom and [overlap the login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1n7e.png).

I would like them to run left to right and stay in their proper box, [like the other languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmATQ.png) do. Note that the language names in this case are an ::after pseudo-element of the #arrow.

```js
    var langclass = "en";
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log("ready");
        $('#lang-select').change(function(){
            document.getElementById("flags").className = $("#lang-select").val();
        });
    });
const langSelect = $("#lang-select");
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("ready");
  let focused = false;
  let updateArrow = function() {
   console.log("update");
    $("#flags").toggleClass("active", focused);
 document.getElementById("arrow").innerHTML = focused ? "⮙" : "⮛";
  };
  langSelect.click(function(ev) {
    if (ev.target !== langSelect[0]) return;
    focused = !focused;
 console.log("select");
    updateArrow();
  });

  let onDeselect = function() {
   console.log("deselect");
    if (!focused) return;
    focused = false;
    updateArrow();
  };
  langSelect.focusout(function() {
    onDeselect();
  });
  langSelect.change(function() {
    onDeselect();
  });
  langSelect.find("option").click(function() {
    onDeselect();
  })
});
```

```css
/*background color to test white text*/
body {
  background-color: black
}
/*The actual CSS*/
#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4vw;
}
.language-picker {
  text-align: right
}
.language-picker label {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 15vw;
  z-index: 1;  
  position: absolute;
  right: 9%;
}
.language-picker option {
  background-color: #111925
}
.language-picker:hover label {
  opacity: 1
}
.language-picker label #flags {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2.5vw;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#lang-select {
    opacity: 0;
 height: 2.75vw;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
    right: 5%;
}
#arrow::after {
  margin-left: 1vw
}

.de #arrow::after {
  content: "Deutsch"
}
.en #arrow::after {
  content: "English"
}
.es #arrow::after{
  content: "Español"
}
.fr #arrow::after {
  content: "Français"
}
.it #arrow::after {
  content: "Italiano"
}
.ko #arrow::after {
  content: "한국어"
}
.pt #arrow::after {
  content: "Português"
}
.zh #arrow::after {
  content: "中文"
}
.de #british-flag, .de #bandera-española, .de #drapeau-français, .de #bandiera-italiana, .de #hangug-guggi, .de #bandeira-portuguesa, .de #zhōngguó-guóqí, .en #deutsche-flagge, .en #bandera-española, .en #drapeau-français, .en #bandiera-italiana, .en #hangug-guggi, .en #bandeira-portuguesa, .en #zhōngguó-guóqí, .es #deutsche-flagge, .es #british-flag, .es #drapeau-français, .es #bandiera-italiana, .es #hangug-guggi, .es #bandeira-portuguesa, .es #zhōngguó-guóqí, .fr #deutsche-flagge, .fr #british-flag, .fr #bandera-española, .fr #bandiera-italiana, .fr #hangug-guggi, .fr #bandeira-portuguesa, .fr #zhōngguó-guóqí, .it #deutsche-flagge, .it #british-flag, .it #bandera-española, .it #drapeau-français, .it #hangug-guggi, .it #bandeira-portuguesa, .it #zhōngguó-guóqí, .ko #deutsche-flagge, .ko #british-flag, .ko #bandera-española, .ko #drapeau-français, .ko #bandiera-italiana, .ko #bandeira-portuguesa, .ko #zhōngguó-guóqí, .pt #deutsche-flagge, .pt #british-flag, .pt #bandera-española, .pt #drapeau-français, .pt #bandiera-italiana, .pt #hangug-guggi, .pt #zhōngguó-guóqí, .zh #deutsche-flagge, .zh #british-flag, .zh #bandera-española, .zh #drapeau-français, .zh #bandiera-italiana, .zh #hangug-guggi, .zh #bandeira-portuguesa {
 display: none
}
.de #deutsche-flagge, .en #british-flag, .es #bandera-española, .fr #drapeau-français, .it #bandiera-italiana, .ko #hangug-guggi, .pt #bandeira-portuguesa, .zh #zhōngguó-guóqí {
 border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 2.5vw;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.de #flags::before {
  content: "DEUTSHCHE";
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: gray;
  background-color: black;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 5vw;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 12vw;
}
.de #deutch1, .de #deutch2, .de #deutch3, .es #española1, .es #española2, .es #española3 {
 height: 33.4%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.fr #français1, .fr #français2, .fr #français3, .it #italiana1, .it #italiana2, .it #italiana3 {
 height: 100%;
  width: 33.4%;
  position: absolute;
}
.de #deutch1 {
  background-color: black
}
.de #deutch2 {
 background-color: red;
  top: 33.3%;
}
.de #deutch3 {
 background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 0;
}
.en #british-flag {
 background-color: #00257d
}
.en #diagonal-white-1, .en #diagonal-white-2, .en #horizontal-white {
 background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #diagonal-white-1, .en #diagonal-white-2 {
    height: 15%;
    top: 43%;
}
.en #diagonal-white-1 {
 transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
.en #diagonal-white-2 {
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
  z-index: 5;
}
.en #red-tl, .en #red-br, .en #red-bl, .en #red-tr {
 background-color: #ff0000;
 height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #red-tl, .en #red-bl {
  z-index: 4;
  top: 25%;
}
.en #red-br, .en #red-tr {
  z-index: 6;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.en #horizontal-white {
 height: 25%;
 z-index: 7;
  top: 37.5%;
}
.en #vertical-white {
 background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
 width: 25%;
 z-index: 8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.5%;
}
.en #horizontal-red, .en #vertical-red {
 background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #horizontal-red {
 height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 42.5%;
}
.en #vertical-red {
 height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 42.5%;
}
.es #española1 {
 background-color: red
}
.es #española2 {
 background-color: yellow;
  top: 33.3%;
}
.es #española3 {
 background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
}
.fr #français1 {
 background-color: blue
}
.fr #français2, .it #italiana2 {
 background-color: white;
  left: 33.3%;
}
.fr #français3, .it #italiana3 {
 background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}
.it #italiana1 {
 background-color: green
}
.ko #hangug-guggi {
 background-color: white
}
.ko #yinyang, .ko #yin, .ko #yang, .ko #hangug1, .ko #hangug2, .ko #hangug3, .ko #hangug4 {
 position: absolute
}
.ko #yinyang {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c40e2f 0%, #c40e2f 50%, #000000 50%, #003478 50%, #003478 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
 height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}
.ko #yin, .ko #yang {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 25%;
}
.ko #yin {
 background: #c40e2f
}
.ko #yang {
 background: #003478;
 right: 0;
}
.ko #hangug1, .ko #hangug2, .ko #hangug3, .ko #hangug4 {
 height: 10%;
  width: 20%;
}
.ko #hangug1 {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 top: 21%;
  left: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug2 {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 21%;
  right: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug3 {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 21%;
 left: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug4 {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 9%;
 bottom: 21%;
}
.ko .fullstripe, .ko .halfstripe {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6.25%;
}
.ko .fullstripe {
 background: #000
}
.ko .halfstripe {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000 45%, #fff 45%, #fff 55%, #000 55%, #000 100%)
}
.pt #bandeira-portuguesa {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #006600 0%, #006600 35%, #FF0000 35%, #FF0000 100%);
}
.pt #bandeira-portuguesa img {
 height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
}
.zh #zhōngguó-guóqí {
 background-color: red
}
.zh #big-star, .zh .little-star {
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
.zh #big-star {
 font-size: 1vw;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
}
.zh .little-star {
 font-size: .3125vw
}
.zh #star1 {
 transform: rotate(20deg);
 top: 12%;
 left: 52%;
}
.zh #star2 {
 transform: rotate(55deg);
 top: 25%;
 left: 60%;
}
.zh #star3 {
 transform: rotate(5deg);
 top: 39%;
 left: 60%;
}
.zh #star4 {
 transform: rotate(25deg);
 top: 52%;
 left: 52%;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
    <!--jquery-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--JS that changes the flag-->
            <script src="#lang-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="language-picker js-language-picker">
                <select name="lang-select" id="lang-select">
                    <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
                    <option value="en">English</option>
                    <option value="es">Español</option>
                    <option value="fr">Français</option>
                    <option value="it">Italiano</option>
                    <option selected="" value="ko">한국어</option>
                    <option value="pt">Português</option>
                    <option value="zh">中文</option>
                </select>
             <label>
                    <div id="flags" class="ko">
                        <div id="arrow">⮛</div>
                        <div id="deutsche-flagge">
                            <div id="deutch1"></div>
                            <div id="deutch2"></div>
                            <div id="deutch3"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="british-flag">
                             <div id="diagonal-white-1">
                                 <div id="red-tl"></div>
                                 <div id="red-br"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="diagonal-white-2">
                                 <div id="red-bl"></div>
                                 <div id="red-tr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id=horizontal-white></div>
                            <div id=vertical-white></div>
                            <div id=horizontal-red></div>
                            <div id=vertical-red></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bandera-española">
                            <div id="española1"></div>
                            <div id="española2"></div>
                            <div id="española3"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="drapeau-français">
                            <div id="français1"></div>
                            <div id="français2"></div>
                            <div id="français3"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bandiera-italiana">
                            <div id="italiana1"></div>
                            <div id="italiana2"></div>
                            <div id="italiana3"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hangug-guggi">
                            <div id="yinyang">
                                <div id="yin"></div>
                                <div id="yang"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="hangug1">
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="hangug2">
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="hangug3">
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                                <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="hangug4">
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                                <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="bandeira-portuguesa">
                              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Coat_of_arms_of_Portugal_%28Lesser%29.svg/300px-Coat_of_arms_of_Portugal_%28Lesser%29.svg.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="zhōngguó-guóqí">
                            <div id="big-star">★</div>
                            <div id="star1" class="little-star">★</div>
                            <div id="star2" class="little-star">★</div>
                            <div id="star3" class="little-star">★</div>
                            <div id="star4" class="little-star">★</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I threw a ton of stuff at it while I was waiting, and something seemed to stick, so it works now. I'm going to screw around a bit and see exactly what it was, then I'll edit this to let people know. Because I didn't see anything on the subject on here.

edit: I specified a height. More specifically, the same height as its main element. So if you want to add a foreign character to an ::after pseudo-element too, remember to make sure that you specify:

CONTENT so that the element appears.

FONT-SIZE if not already specified.

**HEIGHT** so that the oriental characters stay in their box. Adding a height to the main element won't be sufficient. This must be on the pseudo-element.

WIDTH because it's a box.

COLOR so that you can see the text. (optional)

BACKGROUND COLOR during troubleshooting so you can find the element. (optional)

I hope this helps someone one day.

```js
langclass = "en";
$( document ).ready(function() {
 console.log("ready");
 $('#lang-select').change(function(){
  document.getElementById("flags").className = $("#lang-select").val();
 });
});
$('#flags').attr('data-text', '⮛');
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready");
    $( 'div' ).selectmenu({
        open: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#flags').attr('data-text', '⮙');
    }
        });
    
    $( 'div' ).selectmenu({
        close: function( event, ui ) {  
     $('#flags').attr('data-text', '⮛');
    }
    });
});
```

```css
/*just so you can see the white text*/
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.language-picker label {
  opacity: .9
}
/*The actual CSS*/
.language-picker {
  text-align: right
}
#lang-select {
  opacity: 0;
 height: 2.75vw;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
    right: 5%;
}
.language-picker option {
  background-color: #111925
}
.language-picker:hover label {
  opacity: 1
}
.language-picker label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2.5vw;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 9%;
}
#flags {
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 15vw;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
#flags::before {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 15vw;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4vw; 
}

.de#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ Deutsch"
}
.en#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ English"
}
.es#flags::before{
  content: "⮛ Español"
}
.fr#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ Français"
}
.it#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ Italiano"
}
.ko#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ 한국어"
}
.pt#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ Português"
}
.zh#flags::before {
  content: "⮛ 中文"
}
.de #british-flag, .de #bandera-española, .de #drapeau-français, .de #bandiera-italiana, .de #hangug-guggi, .de #bandeira-portuguesa, .de #zhōngguó-guóqí, .en #deutsche-flagge, .en #bandera-española, .en #drapeau-français, .en #bandiera-italiana, .en #hangug-guggi, .en #bandeira-portuguesa, .en #zhōngguó-guóqí, .es #deutsche-flagge, .es #british-flag, .es #drapeau-français, .es #bandiera-italiana, .es #hangug-guggi, .es #bandeira-portuguesa, .es #zhōngguó-guóqí, .fr #deutsche-flagge, .fr #british-flag, .fr #bandera-española, .fr #bandiera-italiana, .fr #hangug-guggi, .fr #bandeira-portuguesa, .fr #zhōngguó-guóqí, .it #deutsche-flagge, .it #british-flag, .it #bandera-española, .it #drapeau-français, .it #hangug-guggi, .it #bandeira-portuguesa, .it #zhōngguó-guóqí, .ko #deutsche-flagge, .ko #british-flag, .ko #bandera-española, .ko #drapeau-français, .ko #bandiera-italiana, .ko #bandeira-portuguesa, .ko #zhōngguó-guóqí, .pt #deutsche-flagge, .pt #british-flag, .pt #bandera-española, .pt #drapeau-français, .pt #bandiera-italiana, .pt #hangug-guggi, .pt #zhōngguó-guóqí, .zh #deutsche-flagge, .zh #british-flag, .zh #bandera-española, .zh #drapeau-français, .zh #bandiera-italiana, .zh #hangug-guggi, .zh #bandeira-portuguesa {
 display: none
}
.de #deutsche-flagge, .en #british-flag, .es #bandera-española, .fr #drapeau-français, .it #bandiera-italiana, .ko #hangug-guggi, .pt #bandeira-portuguesa, .zh #zhōngguó-guóqí {
 border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 2.5vw;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.de #flags::before {
  content: "DEUTSHCHE";
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: gray;
  background-color: black;
 height: 2.5vw;
 width: 5vw;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 12vw;
}
.de #deutch1, .de #deutch2, .de #deutch3, .es #española1, .es #española2, .es #española3 {
 height: 33.4%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.fr #français1, .fr #français2, .fr #français3, .it #italiana1, .it #italiana2, .it #italiana3 {
 height: 100%;
  width: 33.4%;
  position: absolute;
}
.de #deutch1 {
  background-color: black
}
.de #deutch2 {
 background-color: red;
  top: 33.3%;
}
.de #deutch3 {
 background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 0;
}
.en #british-flag {
 background-color: #00257d
}
.en #diagonal-white-1, .en #diagonal-white-2, .en #horizontal-white {
 background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #diagonal-white-1, .en #diagonal-white-2 {
    height: 15%;
    top: 43%;
}
.en #diagonal-white-1 {
 transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
.en #diagonal-white-2 {
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
  z-index: 5;
}
.en #red-tl, .en #red-br, .en #red-bl, .en #red-tr {
 background-color: #ff0000;
 height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #red-tl, .en #red-bl {
  z-index: 4;
  top: 25%;
}
.en #red-br, .en #red-tr {
  z-index: 6;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.en #horizontal-white {
 height: 25%;
 z-index: 7;
  top: 37.5%;
}
.en #vertical-white {
 background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
 width: 25%;
 z-index: 8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37.5%;
}
.en #horizontal-red, .en #vertical-red {
 background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
}
.en #horizontal-red {
 height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 42.5%;
}
.en #vertical-red {
 height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 42.5%;
}
.es #española1 {
 background-color: red
}
.es #española2 {
 background-color: yellow;
  top: 33.3%;
}
.es #española3 {
 background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
}
.fr #français1 {
 background-color: blue
}
.fr #français2, .it #italiana2 {
 background-color: white;
  left: 33.3%;
}
.fr #français3, .it #italiana3 {
 background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}
.it #italiana1 {
 background-color: green
}
.ko #hangug-guggi {
 background-color: white
}
.ko #yinyang, .ko #yin, .ko #yang, .ko #hangug1, .ko #hangug2, .ko #hangug3, .ko #hangug4 {
 position: absolute
}
.ko #yinyang {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c40e2f 0%, #c40e2f 50%, #000000 50%, #003478 50%, #003478 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
 height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
}
.ko #yin, .ko #yang {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 25%;
}
.ko #yin {
 background: #c40e2f
}
.ko #yang {
 background: #003478;
 right: 0;
}
.ko #hangug1, .ko #hangug2, .ko #hangug3, .ko #hangug4 {
 height: 10%;
  width: 20%;
}
.ko #hangug1 {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 top: 21%;
  left: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug2 {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 21%;
  right: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug3 {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 21%;
 left: 9%;
}
.ko #hangug4 {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 9%;
 bottom: 21%;
}
.ko .fullstripe, .ko .halfstripe {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6.25%;
}
.ko .fullstripe {
 background: #000
}
.ko .halfstripe {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, #000 45%, #fff 45%, #fff 55%, #000 55%, #000 100%)
}
.pt #bandeira-portuguesa {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #006600 0%, #006600 35%, #FF0000 35%, #FF0000 100%);
}
.pt #bandeira-portuguesa img {
 height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
}
.zh #zhōngguó-guóqí {
 background-color: red
}
.zh #big-star, .zh .little-star {
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
.zh #big-star {
 font-size: 1vw;
  top: 10%;
  left: 15%;
}
.zh .little-star {
 font-size: .3125vw
}
.zh #star1 {
 transform: rotate(20deg);
 top: 12%;
 left: 52%;
}
.zh #star2 {
 transform: rotate(55deg);
 top: 25%;
 left: 60%;
}
.zh #star3 {
 transform: rotate(5deg);
 top: 39%;
 left: 60%;
}
.zh #star4 {
 transform: rotate(25deg);
 top: 52%;
 left: 52%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<!--jquery-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--JS that changes the flag-->
        <script src="#lang-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="language-picker js-language-picker">
            <select name="lang-select" id="lang-select" label="language">
                <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
                <option selected="" value="en">English</option>
                <option value="es">Español</option>
                <option value="fr">Français</option>
                <option value="it">Italiano</option>
                <option value="ko">한국어</option>
                <option value="pt">Português</option>
                <option value="zh">中文</option>
            </select>
         <label for="lang-select">
                <div id="flags" class="en">
                    <div id="deutsche-flagge">
                        <div id="deutch1"></div>
                        <div id="deutch2"></div>
                        <div id="deutch3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="british-flag">
                         <div id="diagonal-white-1">
                             <div id="red-tl"></div>
                             <div id="red-br"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="diagonal-white-2">
                             <div id="red-bl"></div>
                             <div id="red-tr"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id=horizontal-white></div>
                        <div id=vertical-white></div>
                        <div id=horizontal-red></div>
                        <div id=vertical-red></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bandera-española">
                        <div id="española1"></div>
                        <div id="española2"></div>
                        <div id="española3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="drapeau-français">
                        <div id="français1"></div>
                        <div id="français2"></div>
                        <div id="français3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bandiera-italiana">
                        <div id="italiana1"></div>
                        <div id="italiana2"></div>
                        <div id="italiana3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hangug-guggi">
                        <div id="yinyang">
                            <div id="yin"></div>
                            <div id="yang"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hangug1">
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hangug2">
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hangug3">
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            <div class="fullstripe"></div>
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="hangug4">
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                            <div class="halfstripe"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bandeira-portuguesa">
                          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/Coat_of_arms_of_Portugal_%28Lesser%29.svg/300px-Coat_of_arms_of_Portugal_%28Lesser%29.svg.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div id="zhōngguó-guóqí">
                        <div id="big-star">★</div>
                        <div id="star1" class="little-star">★</div>
                        <div id="star2" class="little-star">★</div>
                        <div id="star3" class="little-star">★</div>
                        <div id="star4" class="little-star">★</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```